# Unique constraint using foreign table column

Tags: symfony, doctrine, constraints

assuming the following tables and columns:

company (id)

product_kind (id, company_id)

product (id, product_kind_id, ean)

---

Product kinds belong to a company:

*@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Company")*

Products belong to a product kind:

*@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ProductKind")*

---

(product.product_kind_id.company_id, product.ean) must be unique. In other words: every product has unique ean across company.

How to make sure this relation is unique?

Comment: You can add your very own unique constraints at the database level: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#table This will prevent you from persisting incorrect data.  And then you might want to use a Symfony validator to prevent you from even trying to store incorrect data.

Comment: I agree with Cerad

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.